# Stuck whilte converting Flux<Employee> to Mono<EmployeeResponse>?

Tags: java-8, reactive-programming

I'm getting `Flux<Employee>` from database and I want to convert the same into `Mono<EmployeeRespnose>` which will contain list of Employees.

```
public Mono<EmployeeResponse> getEmployeeResponse(){
Flux<Employee> employeeFlux = repository
              .findEmployees();   

      return //How to begin here??;
}
```

I don't know how to begin with this. (Operation should be non-blocking)

Please provide any hint/suggestion that how I can begin with this?

```
//class Employee
class Employee{
    private Long ID;
    private String name;
    private String address;

    //getters and setters    
}
//EmployeeResponse class  
class EmployeeResponse{

private int count;

private List<Employee> list;

//getters and setters

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `employeeFlux.collectList()` to get the `Mono<List<Employee>>` and than used `map()` to convert `List<Employee>` to `Mono<EmployeeResponse>`

```
   public Mono<EmployeeResponse> getEmployeeResponse(){
        Flux<Employee> employeeFlux = Flux.empty() ;  

              return employeeFlux.collectList().map(emplist -> {
                  EmployeeResponse response = new EmployeeResponse();
                  response.setCount(emplist.size());
                  response.setList(emplist);
                  return response;
              });
        }
```